# Using SQLFetchScroll to insert data

Tags: c++, sql, database, select

I'm trying to insert into a table data using `SQLFetchScroll`. The problem is if I set `ROWSET_SIZE` to 2, for example, of 1000 lines from source I only insert 500 lines (half) into destination table. I think the problem is with the function `SQLExecute` but I can't figure out how to set it right. Does anyone know how to solve this, please?

```
const SQLUSMALLINT ROWSET_SIZE = 2;
SQLSetStmtAttr(srcHStmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, (SQLPOINTER)ROWSET_SIZE, 0);
SQLLEN FetchOffset = 0;
while (TRUE)
{
    srcReturn = SQLFetchScroll(srcHStmt, SQL_FD_FETCH_NEXT, FetchOffset);
    if (srcReturn == SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND || srcReturn == SQL_ERROR)
    {
        if (srcReturn == SQL_ERROR) showError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, srcHDBC);
        break;
    }
    dstReturn = SQLExecute(dstHStmt);
}
```

Compiler: VS2015 / 64 bit machine.

When using `SQL_FETCH_RELATIVE` I'm having the same results.

```
SQLExecDirect(...);

SQLLEN FetchOffset = 2;
while (TRUE)
{
    srcReturn = SQLFetchScroll(srcHStmt, SQL_FETCH_RELATIVE, FetchOffset);
    if (srcReturn == SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND || srcReturn == SQL_ERROR)
    {
        if (srcReturn == SQL_ERROR) showError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, srcHDBC);
        break;
    }
    dstReturn = SQLExecute(dstHStmt);
}
```

Comment: Why scroll when all you do is SQL_FD_FETCH_NEXT?

Comment: My objective is to receive has many of rows as possible reducing the calls to the source and hopefully inserting the data faster.

Comment: But you are correct, I shouldn't be using FETCH_NEXT. With other cases I'm having the same result.